# Hangfire RecurringJob, Scheduled Every Time or One Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

I am a bit confused with the `Hangfire` implementation for `RecurringJob`. I know that I can schedule a recurring task like this:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("MyName", () => MyProcessor(), "0 6 * * 6", TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

The question that I have is do I need to run the above command every time I restart my app? Or is this something that you run one time, ever?

In otherwords, should my `Startup` run my schedule method(s) or do I run it once via some Admin `Controller` or something...

More info about this `Hangfire` `RecurringJob`: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this AddOrUpdate there is no harm in running this on startup each time.  One thing to keep in mind is, if the schedule has been manually removed from the dashboard then you will re-add it on startup.